# Making a loop in a dictionary with list of keys

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

```
Dict = {
1: ['5', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', 'benign'],
2: ['5', '4', '4', '5', '7', '10', '3', '2', '1', 'benign'],
3: ['3', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '1', '1', 'benign'],
4: ['6', '8', '8', '1', '3', '4', '3', '7', '1', 'benign'],
5: ['4', '1', '1', '3', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', 'benign']}
```

I have a dictionary as above. I want to make a loop something like this

```
q = [3,5]

for x in q:
    print(datadic[][q])
```

So I want to print every 3rd and 5th element of every value. I guess I have to make another loop but I couldn't find out how to print.

Comment: No, i just wrote it like that for a better look

Comment: Don't put that info in a comment. Fix your question!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through your dictionary and then use a list comprehension to print the correct values

```
my_dict = {
    1:['5', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', 'benign'],
    2:['5', '4', '4', '5', '7', '10', '3', '2', '1', 'benign'],
    3:['3', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '1', '1', 'benign'],
    4:['6', '8', '8', '1', '3', '4', '3', '7', '1', 'benign'],
    5:['4', '1', '1', '3', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', 'benign'] }

q = [3,5]

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print ([value[i] for i in q])
```

Which gives:

```
['1', '1']
['5', '10']
['1', '2']
['1', '4']
['3', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

so let me redefine everything in pythonic way to be more readable and let me suggest you my solution for the problem:

```
my_dict = {
    "key1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "key2": [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
}
nth_element_to_print = [3, 5]
for value in my_dict.values():
    for idx in nth_element_to_print:
        print(values[idx])
```

hope it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
     for i in q:
         print(value[i])
```

Comment: What is 'i' stand for?

Comment: @O.Ince: sorry, just a typo. It should be an iteration.